# Llamada a metodo estatico dentro de otro metodo estatico en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un servidor Express donde tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
app.post('/balance', (req, res) => {
    const balance = Wallet.calculateBalance(bc, req.body.address)
    res.json(balance)
})
```

Esta llamada invoca a un metodo estatico Wallet.calculateBalance con los dos parametros:

```js
const Blockchain = require('./blockchain')

const bc = new Blockchain();
const Wallet = require('./wallet')
```

Ok. pero el metodo Wallet.calculateBalance cuyo codigo es este:

```js
static calculateBalance(blockchain, address){
        const utxoSet = Transaction.UTXOSet(blockchain, address)
        let balance = 0
        utxoSet.map(output => {
            return balance+= output.amount
        })
        return balance      
    }
```

llama a otro metodo estatico llamado Transaction.UTXOSet(blockchain, address) pero cuando a través de Postman creo una llamada post a /balance me da error:

TypeError: Transaction.UTXOSet is not a function
    at Function.calculateBalance

No me reconoce esta funcion que si existe en otro archivo. Lo tengo referenciado a traves de la linea require y la funcion es:

```js
static UTXOSet(blockchain, address){
        const outputsAddress = TxOut.outputsOfAddress(blockchain, address)
        const outputsAddressHash = outputsAddress.map(output => ChainUtil.hash(JSON.stringify(output)))
        let totalInputs = TxIn.totalInputs(blockchain)
        totalInputs = totalInputs.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
        let unSpendHashOutputSet = totalInputs.map(input => {
            return outputsAddressHash.filter(output => input.id !== ChainUtil.hash(JSON.stringify(output)))   //Outputs 
        }) 
        unSpendHashOutputSet = unSpendHashOutputSet.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
        const unSpendOutputSet = unSpendHashOutputSet.map(hash => {
            return outputsAddress.filter(output => {
                return ChainUtil.hash(JSON.stringify(output)).toString() === hash.toString()
            })  
        })
        return unSpendOutputSet.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
    }
```

¿ Alguien me puede ayudar ?. Gracias

Comment: Supongo yo tienes a `UTX0Set` dentro de la clase llamada `Transaction` y ademas estas exportando de manera adecuada la clase `Transaction`, ademas en el archivo que intentas usar `Transaction`, imagino lo tienes importado de manera correcta, es esto asi?, porfavor comprueba estos posibles inconvenientes en el proyecto.

Comment: Como menciona @Riven, lo que parece es que te falta inyectar correctamente dicho método, por la forma en que lo llamas diría que estás inyectando el objeto `Transaction`. Debes asegurarte que no solo lo inyectas sino que el mismo es inyectable. Saludos

Comment: Ya esta solucionado. El problema era que al parecer no puedo hacer importaciones cruzadas. Por ejemplo, si tengo la clase Transaction y la clase Wallet, no puedo importar a la vez Wallet en Transaction y Transaction en Wallet. No se porque es esto. Si alguien me lo puede explicar. La solucion que yo tuve es crear metodo no estatico. Gracias